# Joi validation require one of two fields

Tags: javascript, validation, joi

I have the following schema:

```
const validationSchema = Joi.object({
  orderId: Joi.string(),
  cid: Joi.string(),
  address: Joi.string().lowercase()
})
  .xor('orderId', 'cid')
  .required() // also tried commenting out this line
```

I want the `orderId` or the `cid` to be required in the payload. Both can not be present, and at least one of them should be present.

My code seems to be according to the [the documentation](https://joi.dev/api/?v=17.4.0#objectxorpeers-options).

Nevertheless, when I pass a payload like so:

```
{ orderId: '1234', address: 'asdf' }
```

I get an error that `cid` is required. If I pass the `cid` in the payload, then the `orderId` will be required.

What am I missing?

Comment: I tried your example in https://joi.dev/tester/ but without the `required()` and it seems to work as expected

Answer (score 0):

> You can add optional() to your fields in the case of xor

```
const validationSchema = Joi.object({
  orderId: Joi.string().optional(),
  cid: Joi.string().optional(),
  address: Joi.string().lowercase().required() // If this field is mandatory
}).xor('orderId', 'cid');
```